# How to access functions of a parent page of an iframe, in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I have Page1.html which has an iframe. The iframe contains Page2.html. How can I access functions of Page1.html from Page2.html ? I can do it in Internet Explorer, but nothing in Chrome is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
window.parent.yourfunction()
    "<span onclick="parent.myfunc()>test<\span>"
```